# Rails4 Strong parameters without database column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

I have a problem with the mass-assignment and strong parameters. In my model I have several attributes, that are represented through a column in my mysql database. I also have a field, that isn't. I just need it to calculate a value. I don't want to store it in my database.

In my controller I defined the strong parameters:

```
  def timeslots_params
    params.require(:timeslot).permit(:employee_id, :dienstplan_id, :start_date, :start_time)
  end
```

But when I'm trying to access the start_time attribute in my controller, I'm getting the

```
undefined method `start_time' for #<Timeslot:0x007fff2d5d8070> error.
```

The other defined parameters with db columns are present and filled with values. Do I missunderstand the strong parameters and have to define something else?

EDIT: Here is the code, where I call the timeslots_params:

```
  def create
    @e = Timeslot.new(timeslots_params)
    @e.start_date = @e.start_date.to_s + " " + @e.start_time.to_s

    if @e.save
      current_user.timeslots << @e
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render :json => @e }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: can you post code of `Timeslot` model class and where you have defined `start_time` in there?

Comment: Post the action where you are calling `timeslots_params` and getting that error.

Comment: I have added the code to my first post

Comment: It appears to be yelling at you for the `@e.start_time.to_s` call. I agree with @User089247 in wanting to see the model. What happens when you call the `start_time` method on a Timeslot instance in the rails console?

Comment: @nikkon226 I don't have any definitions of start_time in my model. At the Rails 1-3 days, I would just use attr_accessor to define the attribute in my model. But how can I do it in rails 4?

Comment: We need to see where @e.start_time was defined before you use here.

Comment: @AlejandroBabio's answer is correct. You need to define start_time in a method call, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, permit only the params you expect your user send with data. If start_time is not user data for update your db, use this way:

```
params.require(:timeslot).permit(:employee_id, :dienstplan_id, :start_date)
```

Strong parameters prevents save data that user sends and you don't want he/she update.

If you use :start_time, it must be defined at your model.

Ops, I've seen your update:

```
@e.start_date = @e.start_date.to_s + " " + @e.start_time.to_s
```

If you send :start_time to an Timeslot instance them start_time must be a method of Timeslot model. Defined by rails if it is a db field, defined with attr_accesor or att_reader or defined by a def key on your source model.

If not `@e.start_time` trigger `undefined method 'start_time'`.

edited again:

Now, start_time is a model variable. Make sure it is send to the form in the same way that you do with the fields. By default we use an f `<%= f.text_field :the_field %>`. Just don't forget the f.

Now you must permit this field again, if you follow my first advice.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't have to be in the model to be included in the parameters.

Comment: Now, I have defined the `attr_accessor :start_time` in my model. Now I don't get any errors, but the value of start_time is nil. I checked it with pry. But the value is set in the POST request.

Comment: How you expect to be setting this value? The user enter the data, you use Time.now, use a function or ...?

Comment: The user is setting the value in a field of a form and the data is sent to the server via a POST Request. The start_date attribute gets it right value, but the start_time attribute without the database definition doesn't

Comment: I think, I figured the problem out. The Time entered by the user was in the format like "12:00". I tried to enter the time in the "12.00" format and the value was in the variable. So the ":" seems to be the problem. Have you any idea, if there is any rails way, to use the colon? If not, I would just replace it with another character and on the server back to the right format.

Comment: You can see [Time#parse](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.3/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html#method-i-parse) `Time.parse("16:30", now)     #=> 2001-11-29 16:30:00 -0500`

Answer (score 3):

In your Model provide access to the `start_time` field:

```
attr_accessor :start_time
```

If you only need read access:

```
attr_reader :start_time
```

Answer (score 0):

While Alireza's answer couldwork, you might also try defining the setter method yourself, then you can play with the variable before save.

```
def start_time=(time)

    # use variable time to do what you want with the model

end
```